# Doctrine and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-server-2008-r2

I wanted to connect Doctrine with SQL Server 2008. I already have the drivers I need.

This is the error message I get :

> *SQLSTATE[08001]:[MICROSOFT][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Fournisseur de canaux nommés : Impossible d'ouvrir une connexion à SQL Server [2]*

In English, it means it's impossible to open a connection to SQL Server.

This is my code :

```
$config = new Configuration();

$connectionParams = array(
  'dbname' = 'Therefore',
  'user' = 'avanim',
  'password' = null,
  'host' = 'localhost',
  'driver' = 'pdo_sqlsrv');

$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);

$conn->connect();
```

I am new to SQL Server 2008 R2 and I really don't understand where the problem is. I have already checked about account information (user, password, etc...) and it looks fine. Could there be an error with the path or something like that?

Comment: Do you have a sql server running locally ? Try also specifying the default port 1433 and verify that it allows tcp/ip connections in SQL Server Configuration Manager -> Network Configuration -> Protocols -> TCP/IP enabled

Comment: I ve checked but still not working :/